# RPC error: [batch_insert], <MilvusException: code=1

Tags: linux, grpc, grpc-python, milvus, vector-database

I'm inserting 20 million data into milvus database in linux server. while inserting the embedding vectors the the following error is showing up :

```
RPC error: [batch_insert], <MilvusException: (code=1, message=<_MultiThreadedRendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED
        details = "grpc: received message larger than max (704699372 vs. 67108864)"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:127.0.0.1:19530 {grpc_message:"grpc: received message larger than max (704699372 vs. 67108864)", grpc_status:8, created_time:"2023-04-17T11:41:39.477035873+05:30"}"
>)>, <Time:{'RPC start': '2023-04-17 11:41:10.531339', 'RPC error': '2023-04-17 11:41:39.548799'}>
```

i tried updating the MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH but that doesn't work.

```
>>>MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH =256*1024*1024
>>>server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10), options=[('grpc.max_send_message_length',MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH), ('grpc.max_receive_message_length',MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH)])
>>>server.add_insecure_port('[::]:19530')
```

i am new to the milvus database.

Comment: Please use standard measurements. Not everyone will understand what a *crore* is.

Comment: @sai_0033 – 
`256*1024*1024` is still smaller than `704699372`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's not a problem with your server but with Milvus as [this test-case](https://github.com/milvus-io/milvus/blob/master/tests/python_client/testcases/test_insert.py#L1083) suggests that there's a 64mb limit for insertions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I found that is was related to the configuration variables [proxy.grpc.serverMaxRecvSize](https://milvus.io/docs/configure_proxy.md#proxygrpcserverMaxRecvSize) and [proxy.grpc.serverMaxSendSize](https://milvus.io/docs/configure_proxy.md#proxygrpcserverMaxSendSize).

Adjusting these fixed the problem for me.